# Where are the other objects after importing one function from a module

Tags: python-import

According to [this Q&A](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/140d9ha/why_does_python_run_an_entire_module_when_you), All the code in a module is executed even when you only import one function.  This is because of possible dependencies between objects in the module (functions, classes, etc.)

However, only the one imported function is available in the namespace of the code that is doing the importing.  Where are all the other objects in the module, on which the imported function might depend?  Does Python maintain a "private" namespace of all the objects in the module which is inaccessible to all but the imported function?